# Dataframe slicing with more than two dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras

So I'm going through a machine learning tutorial and I'm met with this line of code:

```
pred_list = []

batch = train[-n_input:].reshape((1, n_input, n_features))

for i in range(n_input):   
    pred_list.append(model.predict(batch)[0]) 
    batch = np.append(batch[:,1:,:],[[pred_list[i]]],axis=1)
```

Specifically, what happens inside the for loop. I understand that the first line of code grabs the first value of whatever is predicted, this is only one value. Next it appends the value to the end of batch, this is where I'm confused.

Why is batch in the second line of code `batch[:,1:,:]`? What does that mean? I'm not too sure about dataframe slicing, can someone explain what the second line of code in the for loop means? It would be very much appreciated. Here's the [article](https://medium.com/swlh/a-quick-example-of-time-series-forecasting-using-long-short-term-memory-lstm-networks-ddc10dc1467d) in question. Thank you for reading.

Comment: A `pandas` dataframe is only 2d; `batch` is a numpy `array` (if not a tensorflow object), and can be 3d or more.  It was initially reshaped to 3d.  That size 1 dimension may be a `keras` requirement.

Comment: The 2 appends are quite different.  The list append is efficient and continually grows `pred_list`.  The `np.append` creates a new `batch` array each time, and so is more costly.  But `batch` doesn't change in size. It's a kind of rolling, or moving, collection on the 2nd dimension.

Comment: `train` starts as a row slice of a dataframe, but after passing through the `sklearn` scalar, it must be a numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me `batch` is a numpy array with 3 dimensions of shape `(1, n_input, n_features)`, 1 row, `n_input` columns, and `n_features` depths. `batch[:,1:,:]` would be a slice of `batch` that gets from second to last columns of `batch` (python is 0-based indexing). I am guessing these columns represent `input`s, i.e. all the features of inputs 1 to last.

`batch = np.append(batch[:,1:,:],[[pred_list[i]]],axis=1)` appends `[[pred_list[i]]]` to that slice of `batch` along `axis=1` which is columns. So I am guessing it removes the first input from `batch` and appends the new `[[pred_list[i]]]` as last input to `batch` and re-do this for all inputs in `batch`.

Comment: So it adds another column at the end of batch where the appended value has the same dimensions as batch? After some playing with the code, I found that the `pred_list[i]` returns an array with a single value. e.g. `[[[0.123123]]]`

Comment: @cswannabe correct. keep that in mind that `batch[:,1:,:]` removes column 0 as well while adding that extra column at the end. If your `pred_list[i]` has single value, it means you have only 1 feature. A column could have single value which mean number of rows and depth are 1.

Comment: Also, Appended value has same shape except along the axis it is being appended (here axis=1 or number of columns)

Comment: Alright @Ehsan, I get it now. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @cswannabe My pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

`ndarray` can be indexed in two way,

```
arr = np.array([[[1,2,3],
                 [3,4,5],
                 [7,8,9]]])
```

Either

```
arr[1][0][2] #row, col, layer
```

or

```
arr[1,0,2]  #row, col, layer
```

First index gives you the row, second col, third layer and so on. Both the methods will give you the element present in the 2nd row, 1st column and 3rd layer.

`batch[:,1:,:]` means you want all the rows, all the columns following the 1st column and all the layers.

**P.S**

I have used the word *layers* here, if you know a better word do suggest.